# Is there a pause/play "auto-fetch" option for Twitter?

Tags: twitter

I enjoy checking out [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com/) when I have a minute or two to "catch up" on what is going on outside my home/office, but I hate that I have to manually load new tweets. E.g. click on the "3 new tweets" link.

Is there an option that will allow me to "auto-load" new tweets when they are available?

Likewise, an option to "pause" would be nice, in case I find it overwhelming.

Answer (score 2):

[TwitterFall](http://twitterfall.com) can do this. Just log-in using the button on the left and then check **timeline** on the same panel.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give https://web.tweetdeck.com/ a try, which by now even is an official Twitter client. It doesn't have a pause button but by scrolling down one Tweet the column will stay there even as new Tweets flow in. Then you would have the chance to read at your own pace until you reach the top again.

Comment: I have considered it, I just find that I'm already on the Web in my browser for various links, blogs, work, etc. that the Web version seems to be very handy for.